# building qgis on windows, cmake error

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7

I am trying to build the newest qgis project on windows 7 in my 32 bit machine.

I followed the official instructions and during the cmake configure I get the following error.

> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136
>   (message):   Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version
>   "1.4", but required

The executable python is in cygwin/bin path. the problem is that it finds a lower version of pythoninterp.

Does anyone have ideas?